# Excel spreadsheet as parameter for report

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services, parameters

Has anyone created a report that could use an Excel spreadsheet attached by the user as a parameter for the report? An example would be a list of potential customers in Excel, and whether they exist or don't exist in the database.

I know something like this is easier to accomplish with a manual SSMS query. However, we have several query requests similar to this which are common requests.

Basically want the user to attach their spreadsheet and compare it with data in the database and then spit out a comparison report.

Comment: Your query isn't clear. What do you mean by 'user to attach their spreadsheet'? How does the process work? I understand this sheet has some data which you need it to be compared and then a report generated after. Does that need to be done via SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Use SSIS job to load data from spreadsheet to database and then compare data in usual way with queries.